# Rails, Angularjs, unit test: Unexpected request: GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm following the book "Rails, Angular, Postgres, and Bootstrap"(page 114) and I encounter a problem, where the author didn't.

The chapter I'm on is about testing angularjs in a rails application. Here is my code:

```
   describe("CustomerSearchController", function() {
    describe("Initialization", function() {
        var scope = null,
        controller = null;
        beforeEach(module("customers"));
        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller("CustomerSearchController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it("defaults to an empty customer list", function() {
            expect(scope.customers).toEqualData([]);
        });

    });

    // Problematic code here:
    describe("Fetching Search Results", function() {
        beforeEach(module("customers"));


        var scope = null,
            controller = null,
            httpBackend = null,
            serverResults = [
                {
                    id: 123,
                    first_name: "Bob",
                    last_name: "Jones",
                    email: "bjones@foo.net",
                    username: "jonesy"
                },
                {
                    id: 456,
                    first_name: "Bob",
                    last_name: "Johnsons",
                    email: "johnboy@bar.info",
                    username: "bobbyj"
                }
            ];

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            controller = $controller("CustomerSearchController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));


        it("populates the customer list with the results", function() {
            scope.search("bob");
            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.customers).toEqualData(serverResults);
        });
    });
   });
```

Here is the error I get:

```
$ bundle exec rake teaspoon
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:41239
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:41239/teaspoon/default
.F.

Failures:

  1) CustomerSearchController Fetching Search Results populates the customer list with the results
     Failure/Error: Error: Unexpected request: GET /customers.json?keywords=bob&page=0
No more request expected in http://127.0.0.1:41239/assets/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.self-529586d2fc0e99ea8f36c7780b7c89ac7ff410ba357b533fdcb64eba7b490735.js?body=1?body=1 (line 1421)

Finished in 0.01700 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

teaspoon -s default --filter="CustomerSearchController Fetching Search Results populates the customer list with the results"
rake teaspoon failed
```

I tried to follow every step the author did, but instead of passing, this error occurs. Can anyone see the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I forgot this:

```
    beforeEach(function() {
        httpBackend.when('GET','/customers.json?keywords=bob&page=0').
        respond(serverResults);
    });
```

The author didn't make it entirely clear, where to add this code, so I added it at the wrong place. The working code now looks like this:

```
describe("CustomerSearchController", function() {
    describe("Initialization", function() {
        var scope = null,
        controller = null;
        beforeEach(module("customers"));
        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller("CustomerSearchController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it("defaults to an empty customer list", function() {
            expect(scope.customers).toEqualData([]);
        });

    });

    // Problematic code here:
    describe("Fetching Search Results", function() {
        beforeEach(module("customers"));


        var scope = null,
            controller = null,
            httpBackend = null,
            serverResults = [
                {
                    id: 123,
                    first_name: "Bob",
                    last_name: "Jones",
                    email: "bjones@foo.net",
                    username: "jonesy"
                },
                {
                    id: 456,
                    first_name: "Bob",
                    last_name: "Johnsons",
                    email: "johnboy@bar.info",
                    username: "bobbyj"
                }
            ];

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            controller = $controller("CustomerSearchController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        beforeEach(function() {
            httpBackend.when('GET','/customers.json?keywords=bob&page=0').
            respond(serverResults);
        });

        it("populates the customer list with the results", function() {
            scope.search("bob");
            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.customers).toEqualData(serverResults);
        });
    });
    });
```